# C#: How to check types of two instances

Tags: c#, inheritance, types

I am having trouble getting the right syntax for this.

Say I have two instantiated objects, obj1 and obj2.

Now, I want to check two things:

1) Is the type of obj1 is a **subclass** of the type of obj2.

2) Is the type of obj1 is the **same** as the type of obj2.

I'm pretty sure I can achieve 1) by just doing

```
obj1.GetType().IsSubclassOf(obj2.GetType())
```

But will the above return true if obj1 and obj2 are of the same type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, consult [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> **Return Value**:  `true` if the `Type` represented by the `c` parameter and the current `Type` represent classes, and the class represented by the current `Type` derives from the class represented by `c`; otherwise, `false`.
>
> **This method also returns `false` if `c` and the current `Type` represent the same class.**

If you want to check if two types are the same, you can just compare their `Type`s:

```
obj1.GetType() == obj2.GetType()
```

Comment: Doh! Should have looked it up. Even if I did, I would have had another question about testing type equality that you have already answered for me in this response. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

MSDN says it will return false if obj1 and obj2 are the same class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx

You can just do

```
obj1.GetType().IsSubclassOf(obj2.GetType()) || obj1.GetType() == (obj2.GetType()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
obj2.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(obj1.GetType())
```